# vim hilighting inconsistent with functions that don't have '-' in the name

Tags: bash, vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

Vim seems to color functions differently in bash scripts depending on their having a `-` in the function name. This carries over to the opening and closing braces, as well.

What might be responsible for this behavior? Which coloring is the "correct" one? I'd like to make this consistent.

I've attached a screenshot showing the behavior, note the difference between conda() and the following functions. I'm aware there is unnecessary duplication re: the paths involved, no need to point that out :)

[image: vim function miscolor]

I'm also annoyed by the `3` being colored differently, but that's probably a different question...

As far as environmentals go, this is "vim-nox 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1" on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I have an extensive vimrc:

```
if v:lang =~ "utf8$" || v:lang =~ "UTF-8$"
   set fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,latin1
endif

set nocompatible        " Use Vim defaults (much better!)
set bs=indent,eol,start " allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set ai                  " always set autoindenting on
set nobackup            " stop littering!
set viminfo='20,\"50    " read/write a .viminfo file, don't store more than 50 lines of registers
set history=50          " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler               " show the cursor position all the time
set background=dark     " honestly who uses light background terminals!?
set nowrap              " word wrapping is the devil
set smartcase           " does what it says on the tin
set wildmenu            " completions in status line
set visualbell          " flash instead of making noise
set number              " line numbers yay
set nofoldenable        " code folding is for IDEs, knock it off
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4

" allow F3 to toggle line number display
noremap <F3> :set invnumber<CR>
inoremap <F3> <C-O>:set invnumber<CR>

filetype plugin indent on

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" adjust the line number color, and also switch on search
" pattern hilighting
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  highlight LineNr term=bold cterm=NONE ctermfg=DarkRed ctermbg=NONE gui=NONE guifg=DarkRed guibg=NONE
  set hlsearch
endif

" .sc is a scala file, please to be hilight
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.sc set filetype=scala

if &term=="xterm"
     set t_Co=8
     set t_Sb=m
     set t_Sf=m
endif

" Don't wake up system with blinking cursor:
" (URL removed, site is replaced with a squatter now)
let &guicursor = &guicursor . ",a:blinkon0"

" hex support
nnoremap <C-X> :Hexmode<CR>
inoremap <C-X> <Esc>:Hexmode<CR>
vnoremap <C-X> :<C-U>Hexmode<CR>
command -bar Hexmode call ToggleHex()
function ToggleHex()
  " hex mode should be considered a read-only operation
  " save values for modified and read-only for restoration later,
  " and clear the read-only flag for now
  let l:modified=&mod
  let l:oldreadonly=&readonly
  let &readonly=0
  let l:oldmodifiable=&modifiable
  let &modifiable=1
  if !exists("b:editHex") || !b:editHex
    " save old options
    let b:oldft=&ft
    let b:oldbin=&bin
    " set new options
    setlocal binary " make sure it overrides any textwidth, etc.
    silent :e " this will reload the file without trickeries
              "(DOS line endings will be shown entirely )
    let &ft="xxd"
    " set status
    let b:editHex=1
    " switch to hex editor
    %!xxd -g 1
  else
    " restore old options
    let &ft=b:oldft
    if !b:oldbin
      setlocal nobinary
    endif
    " set status
    let b:editHex=0
    " return to normal editing
    %!xxd -r
  endif
  " restore values for modified and read only state
  let &mod=l:modified
  let &readonly=l:oldreadonly
  let &modifiable=l:oldmodifiable
endfunction
```

Comment: So, on a whim, I copied the file to another name ending in .sh and added a bash-specific shebang. This changed things, in that conda() and conda-deactivate() are now blue... however the middle function, conda-activate(), remains mixed-color. Strange!

Comment: `set ft?` returns what?

Comment: Have a look at `:h ft-sh-syntax`

Comment: `set filetype?` returns sh (and I don't see a bash-specific filetype buried in /usr/share with the rest of them). `:h ft-sh-syntax` isn't very helpful to me. This is a case of the documentation being entirely too verbose. If you can point me to something specific in there, that would be far more helpful! As it is, you just threw a 6,000 line document at me.

Comment: Vim's syntax highlighting is notoriously bad, and if the filetype is correct then you can try different syntax highlighting plugins, but I wouldn't expect much. I love Vim but the coloring can fall apart in complex files, especially bash and perl which both have nightmare syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid it would be like that. I think the "blue" formatting is the desired coloring though, as it seems an inline `foo() { echo stuff; }` formats that way. So there's that.

Comment: According to the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-identifier), Bash function names aren't supposed to contain dashes in the first place.

Comment: Ah, can you add that as an answer so I can accept it?

I guess I'm off to go throw an issue at the shellcheck github then, it doesn't complain about it.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it has been raised in [this issue](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/529) and seems to be POSIX related. Maybe Bash allows dashes as an extension? Shellcheck only complains about it for `#!/bin/sh`, but not for `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Even removing the dashes and setting `g:is_bash` to 1 doesn't help, though. I suspect syntax highlighting is thrown of by declaring the functions within the `if` block. The definitive answer is buried in the [`sh.vim` syntax highlighting source](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/sh.vim).